# Select2 in Angular7: Mix styles of rendered options in a select tag

Tags: html, css, angular, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 to display a list of options that I get through a REST API.
I am currently displaying my data in this way.

Select2 options rendered:
[image: Select2 options rendered]

I am particularly looking forward to the word "Volvo" appearing in **bold** font weight style.
This is the `<select>` tag file where I render the data.

```
<select formControlName="modCar" class="form-control select2" style="width:90%" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.modCar.errors }">
        <option *ngFor="let item of arrCarroc; index as i" value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.nombre}} - {{item.nombreMarca}}</option>
    </select>
```

I already tried to put a `<b>` tag between `{{item.nombreMarca}}` element, define a custom tag in Angular-component CSS, re-define the Select2 CSS class `select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{color:#444;line-height:28px}` but still don't get the result.

Comment: Did you try using `<strong>`? Also have a look at Select2 `templateResult` [Select2Docs](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chenna! Your answer has been very useful to me and I achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this lib [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) to use `::last-word` selector and change last word style.